# Regex to remove leading zeros in a comma separated string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text box where users can enter only numbers separated by commas.

For instance users can enter only **10,11,13,20** and so on. but they shouldn enter as
**010,011,00013,020**.

I tried this one but to no avail

```
    newValue.replace(/[^\d,]+/g, '').replace(/^0+/, '').replace(/,,/g, ',');
```

This restricts only the starting zero,limits the space and numbers only but in-between zeros are not restricted.

Is there any regular expression to replace all the leading zeros in the string above to make it as **10,11,13,20** allowing only one comma in between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using capturing group:

```
'010,011,00013,020'.replace(/(^|,)0+/g, '$1')
// => "10,11,13,20"
```

**UPDATE**

To avoid remove all `0` from `0000` or `0`, use following: (negative lookahead assertion)

```
'00'.replace(/(^|,)0+(?!$)/g, '$1')
// => "0"
```

---

Using word boundary (`\b`):

```
'010,011,00013,020'.replace(/\b0+(?!$)/g, '')
// => "10,11,13,20"
'000'.replace(/\b0+(?!$)/g, '')
// => "0"
```

Comment: This works fine..but it allows characters and spaces in between. Is there any way that we can eliminate space and characters in between. I somehow achieved by                               newValue.replace(/(^|,)0+/g, '$1').replace(/[^\d,]+/g, '');

Comment: @JovialAndree, Do another replacement: `....replace(/\b0+(?!$)/g, '').replace(/[^\d,]/g, '')`

Comment: Thanks @falsetru atlast i have done by this newValue.replace(/(^|,)0+/g, '$1').replace(/[^\d,]+/g, '').replace(/,,/g, ',');

Comment: @JovialAndree, You can replace the last part with this: `.replace(/,{2,}/g, ',.')` to handle the case where more than 2 consecutive commas.

Answer (score 4):

Very easy, match sequences of digits, for each match remove the 0es on the left:

```
replace(/0*([0-9]+)/g, "$1")
```

Sample and explanation here: http://regex101.com/r/xW6dC2

Edit (disallow single digit 0es):

```
replace(/0+,?|0*([0-9]+,?)/g, "$1")
```

http://regex101.com/r/qT7zU1

Comment: Its working fine,But the series shouldn allow zero as a single number.It can come as 10,20,30 but not as 0,10,20,0

Comment: ok fixed; it was not clearly specified in the question though